# Jest + kendo-angular-grid => Class constructor EventEmitter_ cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: jestjs, angular13, kendo-angular-ui

I get an error while running my Jest test file:

```
TypeError: Class constructor EventEmitter_ cannot be invoked without 'new'

  at new ZoneAwareEventEmitter (node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/common/event-emitter.js:16:28)
  at new GridComponent (node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-grid/dist/npm/grid.component.js:328:1)
```

I tried all possibilities for target (es5, es6, es2019 ...) and module (commonJs, es6, es2015, es2020....)

"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
"target": "es2019",
"module": "es2020",
"moduleResolution": "node",
},

package.json

```
{
  "name": "jest-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "jest",
    "test-esm": "node --experimental-vm-modules --no-warnings node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js -c=jest-esm.config.mjs --no-cache",
    "test:w": "jest --watchAll",
    "cover": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.21.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.3.0",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "3.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "1.2.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "4.0.5",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "7.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "3.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "1.16.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "6.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "8.0.8",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "6.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "6.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "3.1.3",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "1.5.6",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "3.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "4.0.4",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "6.1.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^11.1.1",
    "typescript": "~4.5.2"
  }
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
  ],
  preset: "jest-preset-angular",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"],
};
```

setup-jest.ts

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

app.component.html

```
<kendo-grid></kendo-grid>
```

app.component.spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let app: AppComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [AppModule],
    providers: [],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
  }).compileComponents();
 
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  app = fixture.componentInstance;
});

describe('class AppComponent{}', () => {

  it('Should create the app', () => {
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Telerik is aware of the described issue as Jest preset isn't working with Angular v13 without the Ivy packages. The team is currently in the process of switching to the Ivy library format expected to release in R2 May 2022. The progression can be followed in the following thread in the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/3502
After the switch to the Ivy engine, the issue will be resolved.

Comment: @MStephan I have exactly the same issue currently, unfortunately, updating the Grid to v7 (which should be Ivy-ready, right?) did not change a thing. Is it working for anyone yet?

Comment: I have opened a ticket on Github: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular/issues/3660

Comment: i've got the same anwser from Telerik on my ticket. Very disappointing.

Comment: also found the same bug, so silly, even changing the package.json to point to the esm files and change those to .mjs will work

Answer (score 0):

For those who are just testing components that use the grid (instantiating), you can mock it!

```
jest.mock('@progress/kendo-angular-grid');
```

Comment: Can you show us where to put this in our test file?